# how can we access customer session in checkout

Tags: magento2, database, customer, session, quote

I have one special field called some_id in customer data and I want to save the some_id and quote_id in database.

I am using `sales_quote_save_after`event to save both ids. But my customer session is not accessible here.

Can anyone knows here how can we do that?

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(   
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
){
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

 public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/cust.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('new observer');
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
       $logger->log("Customer Name ". $this->customerSession->getName());
      $logger->log("Quote id ". $quote->getId());

    }
```

Comment: "But my customer session is not accessible here." how are oyu trying to access it? you need to provide us code

Comment: updated the code

Comment: and what is not working? are you getting an exception?

Comment: not getting customer data, am logged in

Comment: am expecting customer data here , am getting nohing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$logger->log("Customer Name ". $this->customerSession->getCustomerData()->getName());
```